# Android - installed certificate but how use it for connection?

Tags: android, https, certificate

I installed certificate (user) and i need to use it for connection with server. Do i need to do something more to use it for secure connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the certificate by copying it to application-specific storage.

Setting up a custom KeyStore containing the certificate, and then using it to create a custom SSLContext.

Once we have a reference to a File containing the client certificate and the password for the certificate, we load it into an appropriate KeyStore.

```
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
fis = new FileInputStream(certificateFile);<br>keyStore.load(fis, clientCertPassword.toCharArray());
```

Now that we have the KeyStore containing the client certificate, we can use it to build an SSLContext:

```
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
kmf.init(keyStore, clientCertPassword.toCharArray());
KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);
```

The SSLContext can then be used with an HTTPUrlConnection to connect to the server:

```
String result = null;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

try {
    URL requestedUrl = new URL(url);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) requestedUrl.openConnection();
    if(urlConnection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
        ((HttpsURLConnection)urlConnection)
             .setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    }
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1500);
    lastResponseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
    result = IOUtil.readFully(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    lastContentType = urlConnection.getContentType();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    result = ex.toString();
} finally {
    if(urlConnection != null) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/https-with-client-certificates-on/